# Ubuntu 16.04 - Seeing my wireless card as wired

Tags: networking, drivers, reboot, 16.04

After installing Ubuntu 16.04, there is weird, intermittent behavior after random reboots. I'll boot everything up, and I won't be able to connect to WiFi. When I click on the network icon, or go into network settings, the wireless card I have is instead shown as a wired connection that is not connected. It is not seen as wireless at all.

I have a Gigabyte GB-WB867D-I WiFi/Bluetooth card in my desktop. This issue did not occur with Ubuntu 15.10.

Again, this only happens after random reboots, and if I reboot again it goes away, but it's an issue I'm hoping to resolve permanently. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. One workaround is to reboot network-manager with this command line : "sudo service network-manager restart"

Comment: I notice this was posted before the official release date for Xenial - is it still a problem in the official release?  If so, this question could be reopened (or closed for a different reason, if applicable).  Similarly, if you've found an update fixed the problem, that would be great to hear.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a similar problem with a USB wireless adapter, which I was able to get working just by unplugging and plugging back in again.

Comment: The latest on this bug for can currently be found at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1584970.  Currently it looks like they need someone experiencing the problem to file a bug upstream.

Comment: I've filed a report in the Gnome Bugzilla at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767243